# How to correctly interpret DateTime.UTCNow serialized as json, taking time zones into account?

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, timezone, utc

We have server code that uses DateTime.UTCNow and is serialized as

```
2015-02-17T12:38:58.3220885Z
```

What is the correct way to interpret these serialized dates client side, taking time zones into account?

I am trying to track down a reported bug where the times appear to be incorrect and 'in the future' - at the client - I have seen no evidence of this however. The idea is for the server and client to simply be working with the same point in time.

Comment: What do you mean by "taking time zones into account"? You've specified a UTC time - that's what the `Z` means. What do you *want* to do on the client side? You haven't told us anything about what you're trying to achieve, so we can't really tell you the correct way of doing anything.

Comment: It's exactly what it says it is. It's 17 february 2015 at 12:38:58 at the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
var date = new Date('2015-02-17T12:38:58.3220885Z');
date.toString()
```

Will give the date according to the local time zone.

Comment: ... assuming that's what the OP wants to achieve. It's very unclear at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet : He stated : correct way to interpret these serialized dates client side, taking (client side) time zones into account? What is so unclear?

Comment: Well you've *assumed* the OP means the client side time zone... and *assumed* the OP wants to convert it into a string. We simply don't know that though. "interpret" could mean any number of things. It's just a really bad question, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet :  Well their are probably two time zones "server  time zone" and "client  time zone". He is getting the value from the server so its clearly in "server time zone" then obviously he would like to get it converted to "client time zone."

Comment: No, it's not in the server time zone - it's in UTC. And therer are *multiple* other time zones it could be. For example, I could be talking from the UK to a server in Germany, looking at the details of an event taking place in California, attended by a friend who lives in Paris.

Comment: Their are two events : Production and Consumption. Usually a producer is a single entity (Server) and their are several consumers (Client). I think it is pretty simple to understand.

Comment: It's for a lastUpdated field, we just need to display sane times to the end user, regardless of where they are, so the times make sense in their time zone, so this looks like the right answer.

Comment: @void yes that seems right, the value is created at the server, and could be consumed client side in any time zone

Comment: You seem to have made a lot of assumptions there. As it happens, if it's a lastUpdated time, then it *is* going to be server-generated - but that's still an assumption. Imagine a calendar application: the producer of a time is usually a person, and there can be multiple consumers in multiple different time zones. If you try to look at *every* date/time problem in the way you've dealt with this question, you'll run into problems.

Comment: (Although reading the question again, if the server is using `DateTime.UtcNow`, that certainly *is* server-generated course. I still think the question is unclear about what "correct way to interpret" really means... the OP should take more time to be clear in future.)

Comment: I'm with Jon on this - the question is poorly written.  In particular, it only asks how to "interpret" the value.  The given answer gives one way of *parsing* and *reformatting* the value.  While the output of `date.toString()` in most browsers will show some time zone information, there are *many* more ways to format the output - hence why libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) exist.  Also, parsing ISO8601 strings with the `Date` constructor is not necessarily supported in all browsers.  (IE9+ should be ok)